# Is there a missing condition in this statement regarding Borel measurability

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, borel-sets

I'm self-studying measure theory. I stumbled upon this statement:

> If $X \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function, then $f$ is a Borel measurable function if and only if $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is a Borel set for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

The forward direction is easy ($f$ is Borel measurable $\implies$ $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is a Borel set for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$). My question is about the backward direction: don't we need to assume that $X$ is Borel measurable? If not, how can I prove the backward direction?

Comment: I assume this means Borel measurable wrt the subspace topology on $X$. In this topology $X$ is Borel (indeed, open), even though it might not be on $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Your assumption is correct, but I don't quite understand you comment?

Comment: You asked if we need to assume that $X$ is borel in $\mathbb R$. I am not sure exactly what your confusion is, and don't have time to post a real answer right now, so I left a comment addressing one possible source of confusion - $f^{-1}(-\infty,\infty) = X$, but $X$ is not borel in $\mathbb R$. This is, of course, not actually an issue because $X$ _is_ borel in itself, as my comment suggests. I'll write a real answer later today when I have more time, if nobody beats me to it ^_^

Comment: @user1691278 It is assumed that $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ is a Borel space. As in this case $X$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, you can assume that $X$ is equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor When you say $X$ is Borel, do you mean that you can define a Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $X$? If so, why?

Comment: @Mrcrg Why can I assume that $X$ is equipped with Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: You can define a Borel $\sigma$-algebra in $X$. Just take $(X,\mathcal{B}(X))$. 
Where $\mathcal{B}(X)=\{ A \subset X : A=B\cap X \text{ where } B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) \}$

Comment: @user1691278 It is necessary to see where in the theory you are. If you saw Borel's algebra only in $\mathbb{R}$, then you will have to assume that $X$ is borel measurable. Because $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=X$.
But the Borel $\sigma$-algebra can be defined in any topological space.

Comment: @Mrcrg I have only seen the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on R, defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ tells me that $X$ is a Borel set, but how does that help? Is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$ also a $\sigma$-algebra on any of its subsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f : X \to \mathbb R$ such that, for each $a$, $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ is borel in $X$. We want to show that $f$ is borel - that is, we want to show that $f^{-1}(U)$ is borel for each $U \subseteq \mathbb R$ open.

Since every open set $U$ is a union of basic opens (the intervals), it suffices to show $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is borel for every $a,b \in \mathbb R$.

But we know that 
$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N} \left ( a,b - \frac{1}{n} \right ] = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigg ( (a,\infty) \setminus (b - \frac{1}{n}, \infty) \bigg )$$

So

$$f^{-1}(a,b) = f^{-1} \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \bigg ( (a,\infty) \setminus (b - \frac{1}{n}, \infty) \bigg ) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \big [ f^{-1}(a,\infty) \setminus f^{-1}(b - \frac{1}{n}, \infty) \big ]$$

Which is borel since set operations and countable unions of borel sets are borel.

---

I hope this helps ^_^